# How do I make a TextBox that can grow wider than its parent?

Tags: wpf, textbox

Is there any way I can make a WPF TextBox dynamically grow beyond the bounds of its parent?

For example, I am allowing a user to type in an XPath string that could be very long (wide), I would like one of two possible things to happen:

1. The textbox could grow wider when the user types a certain amount of characters.
   or
2. When the user initially clicks on the textbox, it kind of 'pops-out' and is very wide, wider than its container.

Is this possible?

Comment: Have you considered using horizontal scroll viewer instead?

Comment: I considered it, but I might need a combination of that and what I asked for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set a negative Margin to allow it to grow wider than its parent.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid Margin="50">
        <TextBlock Margin="0,0,-50,0" Text="This is a very long text." />
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: So I would need to shift the margin and grow the width at the same time?  Can you modify the margin in the code behind?  If so, how?  I tried txtBox.Margin.Left -= 10 but it isn't allowed.

Comment: If your TextBlock.HorizontalAlignment is Stretch and no Width is set it grows automagically. You need to set the whole Margin like `txtBox.Margin = new Thickness(txtBox.Margin.Right, ..., txtBox.Margin.Bottom)`

Comment: Also, will this work considering the parent container is a dialog?

Comment: That depends on how the dialog is done. If it is another Window, then you cannot extend beyond the border there. You'd need to "fake" new borders and have an transparent margin around them in which to grow.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

1. Put both the *ParentControl* and the `TextBox` inside a `Canvas`.
2. Locate the `TextBox` using fixed or dynamic coordinates relative to the *ParentControl*.
3. Set the `TextBox` Z-Index to higher value of the *ParentControl*.
4. Relocate and/or expend the `TextBox` based on `TextBox` events.